# SQL SELECT only rows where a max value is present, and the corresponding ID from another linked table

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have a simple Parts database which I'd like to use for calculating costs of assemblies, and I need to keep a cost history, so that I can update the costs for parts without the update affecting historic data.

So far I have the info stored in 2 tables:

tblPart:

```
PartID | PartName
1      | Foo
2      | Bar
3      | Foobar
```

tblPartCostHistory

```
PartCostHistoryID | PartID | Revision | Cost
1                 | 1      | 1        | £1.00
2                 | 1      | 2        | £1.20
3                 | 2      | 1        | £3.00
4                 | 3      | 1        | £2.20
5                 | 3      | 2        | £2.05
```

What I want to end up with is just the PartID for each part, and the PartCostHistoryID where the revision number is highest, so this:

```
PartID | PartCostHistoryID
1      | 2
2      | 3
3      | 5
```

I've had a look at some of the other threads on here and I can't quite get it. I can manage to get the PartID along with the highest Revision number, but if I try to then do anything with the PartCostHistoryID I end up with multiple PartCostHistoryIDs per part.

I'm using MS Access 2007.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mihai's (very concise) answer will work assuming that the order of both

- [PartCostHistoryID] and
- [Revision] for each [PartID]

are always ascending.

A solution that does not rely on that assumption would be

```sql
SELECT 
    tblPartCostHistory.PartID, 
    tblPartCostHistory.PartCostHistoryID
FROM
    tblPartCostHistory
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            PartID,
            MAX(Revision) AS MaxOfRevision
        FROM tblPartCostHistory
        GROUP BY PartID
    ) AS max
        ON max.PartID = tblPartCostHistory.PartID
            AND max.MaxOfRevision = tblPartCostHistory.Revision
```

Comment: +1 This approach will not break if cost revisions are not entered chronologically, or when data entry errors get corrected later.

Comment: Have tested this and it works perfectly. As mentioned, Mihai's answer does work but this is a more robust way to do it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is query

```
select PartCostHistoryId, PartId from tblCost
where PartCostHistoryId in 
(select PartCostHistoryId from 
   (select * from tblCost as tbl order by Revision desc)  as tbl1
group by PartId
)
```

Here is SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19c2d/12

Comment: @marc_s: Yes,,and also I've corrected the query with Fiddle. :)

Comment: The Fiddle shows that the query works in MySQL, but unfortunately it does not work in Access: "You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'PartCostHistoryId' as part of an aggregate function."

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PartID,MAX(PartCostHistoryID) FROM table GROUP BY PartID
```